# Dual curve of the lemniscate of Bernoulli?

Tags: algebraic-curves, mathematica

Does anybody happen to know the homogeneous equation $F(u,v,w) = 0$ for the algebraic curve *dual* to the lemniscate of Bernoullli:
$$ F(x,y,x) = (x^2 + y^2)^2 - A (x^2 -y^2)z^2 = 0?$$

I looked at the equation of the tangent $(\partial F/\partial x, \partial F/\partial y, \partial F/\partial z) =: (u,v,w)$ i.e.:

$$ u = 4x(x^2+y^2) - 2Axz^2 \\  v = 4y(x^2+y^2) + 2Ayz^2 \\  w = 2Az(y^2-x^2)$$

But I wouldn't know how to guess an equation between $u, v$ and $w$?

Is there somebody that can use Mathematica to Eliminate the solution?

Comment: The lemniscate of Bernoulli is a plane curve. Why do you have three arguments for $F$?

Comment: I use homogeneous coordinates. So by putting $x'=x/z, y'=y/z, z'=z/z = 1$ one gets the normal (affine) equation. Or just by putting $z=1$. Also $[u,v,w]$ are homogeneous line coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a trial version of Mathematica I used the Eliminate function like this:
Eliminate[ {(x^2 + y^2) ^2 == A*(x^2-y^2) * z^2, u== 2*x*(x^2 + y^2) - A*x * z^2, v == 2*y*(x^2 + y^2) + A*y * z^2, w == A*z *(y^2 - x^2)}, {x,y,z}].

And the result is:
$$
F^d = A^3(u^2 - v^2)^3 + A^2(15u^4 +78u^2v^2 +15v^4)w^2 + A(48u^2 - 48 v^2) w^4 - 64w^6  = 0 
$$

The lemniscate has degree 4 and 3 ordinary nodes. The dual curve should then have degree
$4*3 - 2* 3 =6$ which seems to hold.

I checked the result using Mathematica again and it turns out to be correct.
With the help of several functions:

- dualLemnVec[{u_, v_, w_}, A_] := A^3 *(u^2 -  v^2 )^3 +  A^2 *(15 (
  u^2 +  v^2)^2 + 48 u^2 v^2 )w^2 + A *48*( u^2 -  v^2)w^4 - 64 w^6
- lemn[{x_,y_,z_}]:=(x^2+y^2)^2 - A*(x^2 -y^2)*z^2
- paramLemn[t_]:={Sqrt[A]*(t + t^3),Sqrt[A]*( t-t^3), 1+ t^4}
- Simplify[lemn[paramLemn[t]]] = 0 (doublecheck)
- diffparamLemn[t_] := {Sqrt[A]*(1 +3* t^2), Sqrt[A]*(1 - 3*t^2), 4* t^3}
- paramDualLemn[t_]:=Cross[paramLemn[t],diffparamLemn[t]]
- Simplify[dualLemnVec[paramDualLemn[t], A]] = 0 (yes!)

Also Mathematica calculated in a fraction of a second the dual of the dual of the lemniscate and it turned out to be the lemniscate again.

D[dualLemnVec[{u,v,w},A],u] = 6 A^3 u (u^2-v^2)^2+A^2 (96 u v^2+60 u (u^2+v^2)) w^2+96 A u w^4.
Likewise the partial derivates w.r.t. v and w.

Eliminate[{A^2 *(-15 u^4 - 78 u^2 v^2 - 15 v^4) w^2 + A* (-48 u^2 + 
       48 v^2) w^4 + 64 w^6 == A^3 * ( u^6 - 3 u^4 v^2 + 3 u^2 v^4 - v^6),
  x == 6 *A^3 *u (u^2 - v^2)^2 + A^2 *(96 u v^2 + 60 u (u^2 + v^2)) w^2 +  A* 96 u w^4,
  y == -6 *A^3 *v (u^2 - v^2)^2 +A^2 * (96 u^2 v + 60 v (u^2 + v^2)) w^2 -  A* 96 v w^4, 
  z == 2*A^2* (48 u^2 v^2 + 15 (u^2 + v^2)^2) w + 192 *A*(u^2 - v^2) w^3 -     384 w^5}, {u, v, w}]

Answer surprisingly or not: (x^2 + y^2) ^2 == A*(x^2-y^2) * z^2

Some easy points of the dual lemniscate:

- $(1,\pm 1, 0)$: two asymptotes $x=\pm y$, their points of infinity are cusps;
- $(\pm \sqrt{1/A}, 0, 1)$: two points on the x-axis;
- $(\pm i\sqrt{8/A}, 0, 1)$: two imaginary points on the x-axis;
- $(0,\pm \sqrt{8/A}, 1)$: two nodes on the y-axis;
- $(0, \pm i\sqrt{1/A}, 1)$: two imaginary points on the y-axis;

Comment: Dear @Gerard, thanks for your nice answer. I tried to imitate your method via Mathematica to find the dual curve of another plane curve, but I ran into some trouble. Could you take a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220193/finding-dual-plane-curve-using-eliminate)?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, bc. 5 year ago I was studying this and familiar with it, but since then I moved on to other interest and it's too difficult to remember now.